# Android Studio shows C++ file icon on every file

Tags: android-studio

After updating Android Studio to version `4.1` every file icon in the project is shown as a `C++` icon. Is there any way to repair this?  This is how it looks:

[image]

You can see every file, no matter what extension, has [image] icon. I created new projects and checked the old ones but the effect is the same everywhere.

---

#### In my case, the error disappeared after updating Android Studio to version `2020.3.1`.

Comment: I have the same issue after updating to Android Studio v4.1 on two different PCs (Windows 7 and Windows 10)

Comment: Had so many stupid issues after updating it, had to invalidate cache and manually delete cached folders (.gradle & .idea) so it would **finally** even run Lint checks again. Without that is was just all white text.

Comment: Same problem on macOS.

Comment: Same problem in the version control section

Comment: Was anyone able to find a solution for it?

Comment: Someone has reported the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173142942

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Try using ExtraIcons Plugin may be it will solve this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing you cache? There is a bug in in the IDE's icon cache. After you restart Android Studio, the IDE will rebuild the icon cache, and the icons should appear correctly.

If this doesn't work, you can also try resetting Android Studio to its default settings (File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings). Beware though, as this will reset all settings and preferences - so be sure to back up any important configuration files before doing this.