# Android Studio Ui Bug: .kt files shown as C++ files

Tags: android-studio, file

I've recently updated Android Studio to version 4.1
I just wanted to commit and all of my files get shown as C++ files in this window. In the project overview they've got their right icon.
Any solutions?

[image: image of c++ files]

EDIT: Invalidate caches and restart doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Observing the same issue right now. Any opinions?

Comment: Same here in 2021 with 4.1.2 version. Related issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376608/android-studio-shows-c-file-icon-on-every-file In Canary version 4.2 the issue is fixed