# Android Studio shows type mismatch error for compilable kotlin code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, type-mismatch

In our team, there are two groups of members.

For the first group, Android Studio offers to simplify the code like below and transform redundant declaration of types to lambdas.

For the second group, Android Studio marks the simplified code as incorrect with a type mismatch compilation error. But the code still compilable.

But no one knows what settings to tweak for the second group to join the first group.

Does anyone know, what settings are responsible for this behavior?
[image][image]

Comment: do both groups make use of the same versions of android studio and the kotlin plugin ?

Comment: most likely not. But I'm trying to figure out, what is exact point

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks, you inspired me to update Android Studio and Kotlin plugin, which solved the problem. 

Hopefully, Google will solve the buggy-af problem of the newest Android Studio as well.

Comment: no problem, happy to help :)  i've been using kotlin for a few years now and plugin updates sometimes cause or fix these kinds of issues, i don't think this is specifically an android studio/lint issue, but i could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Studio to the most recent version (currently 4.1.2) caused Studio to offer to update Kotlin-plugin to 1.4.30 version, which, I believe, solved the problem.

If I'm not mistaking, there was no option to update Kotlin-plugin to 1.4.30 in Android Studio 4.0.2, at least Studio didn't offer to do so and there was no Install-button in Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates settings section.

But I intentionally used a bit outdated version, because AndroidStudio 4.1.2 is buggy as hell.

**UPD**

Because recent Android Studio has a huge bunch of bugs like [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173126306) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64376608/android-studio-shows-c-file-icon-on-every-file) making it almost impossible to use, there is no option for me to stay on 4.1.2 until these bugs are fixed.

So I downgraded studio to 4.0.2 again, but installed Kotlin plugin of 1.4.21 version manually. You can do so by downloading it from [official JetBrains site](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions/stable) and following the screenshot instruction below.

So now I have stable Android Studio and recent Kotlin-plugin which solves type-mismatch problem.

[image]